# Change "parent" site to "child" site or use the actual site name

Tags: meta, discussion

This is for this meta site but there's no meta-MSO, I suppose.

Is it just me that interprets a "meta" site as higher-level than its "parent" site? For one thing, I'd never consider my kids an "abstraction" from me.

I think it's better if we just show the actual site name. So for MSO it just says SO.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the request to [rename it "main"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61021/se-2-0-ui-jargon-in-the-interface-getting-rid-of-parent), but on that one Jeff said he didn't like main because it's too close to meta and asked for other suggestions, so I guess it probably shouldn't be closed since it suggests other things

Comment: "main" is very bad indeed. Sorry I didn't find that question, otherwise I would've answered there.

Comment: Your children *are* an abstraction from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its a matter of "higher".  The meta site can not exist without the parent site so parent isn't a bad name.

Another suggestion would be **primary** or **prime**.

Comment: I agree with the existential part. By "higher" I meant higher level of involvement. You'd only meta if you care about the "parent" site. Some "plz send me teh codez" guy wouldn't even know what meta means.

Comment: I doubt if the "plz send me teh codez" guys know anything, but that is a different story.